# there is an question, i want query all data from realm in Swift and there

Tags: ios, swift, realm

this is a question, i want read all data from realm in swift, and throw an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8)
but I can insert data, please help me find where goes wrong

```
    static func customJudge(content: String, mobile: String) -> String {
        do {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let ruleInfo = RuleModel()
            ruleInfo.content = "123"
            ruleInfo.actionType = "提醒"
            ruleInfo.clickType = "abc"
            ruleInfo.id = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(ruleInfo)
            }
            let resultList =  realm.objects(RuleModel.self)
            if !resultList.isEmpty {
                print("is not null")
            } else {
                print("is null")
            }
        } catch {
            print("exception is :\(error)")
        }
        return ""
    }
```

let resultList =  realm.objects(RuleModel.self) this line is appear a error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8)

I want query out all data

Comment: There are a few issues in the code but it works for me. First, its not clear why the func is declared as `static` so I just used `func`. Also, `try!` overrides the `do:catch` block so remove the `!`. Other than that, I copy and pasted your code into a fresh project it worked perfectly. It wrote out a Rule object, then printed `is not null` to console. That tells me that either there's a version issue with your Realm or Realm was not installed in the project correctly. Either way, that code is not the issue. Perhaps the `RuleModel` is the issue - can you include it?

Answer (score -1):

The error EXC_BAD_ACCESS typically occurs when there is a memory access issue.
In your case, the issue may be related to how you are managing the Realm instance.

It's crucial to make sure the Realm instance you use to fetch data is still valid and hasn't been deallocated.

You can this modified version of your code that ensures proper Realm management :

```
 static func customJudge(content: String, mobile: String) -> String {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let ruleInfo = RuleModel()
        ruleInfo.content = "123"
        ruleInfo.actionType = "提醒"
        ruleInfo.clickType = "abc"
        ruleInfo.id = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(ruleInfo)
        }
        
        // Make sure you have a valid Realm instance here
        let anotherRealm = try Realm()
        let resultList = anotherRealm.objects(RuleModel.self)
        
        if !resultList.isEmpty {
            print("is not null")
        } else {
            print("is null")
        }
    } catch {
        print("exception is: \(error)")
    }
    return ""
}
```

In this code, I've created a separate Realm instance (anotherRealm) for fetching data after writing to the database. This should help avoid any issues related to accessing a Realm instance that might have become invalid.

Make sure you also check your data model (RuleModel) and ensure it matches your database schema. Issues with data models can sometimes lead to unexpected crashes as well.

Comment: While all answers are appreciated, the code in this answer doesn't really address the question... but more importantly, a Realm var will stay within scope within a single function. e.g. it will not invalidate within the scope of a function. Once the realm has been instantiated, it's valid throughout out the function. That would be like saying `let x = 1` and then at some point further down in the function, x has to be set to 1 again because it went out of scope - that obviously wont happen. That means a realm only has to be created once within any given function.